# Is there an alternative to using Gmaps.loadMaps when loading HTML/JS that contains Gmaps4Rails via AJAX?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ajax, google-maps, gmaps4rails

I'm using Gmap4Rails in the body of a form that is loaded via Ajax. There are custom fields in the form and some of them may be location pickers that I have working on a non-Ajax version of the form.

With the Ajax version of the form, I'm getting "Gmaps.my_map_id" undefined errors.

In the non-Ajax version of the form, I call Gmaps.loadMaps via JavaScript in the HTML page head for "window.onload" as is the normal practice with Gmaps4Rails.

However, this won't work in the context of Ajax, as the map(s) haven't been defined at window.onload time.

In my form, I also define a callback per Gmaps map object. This is what seems to be failing with the "undefined" error, even when I do a "Gmaps.loadMaps();" script directly before the first callback is defined in the code that is loaded by Ajax.

Basically it goes like this in code order:

1. in a loop, gmaps4rails partial is called to output each map custom field
2. after that loop finishes, Gmaps.loadMaps() is called once
3. in another loop, each Gmaps map object has the JS for its callback added

Any suggestions on how to get this working?

Comment: If you add ':last_map => false' in map options, 'window.onload' won't be adde in any partial. This way you can trigger the creation of the maps whenever you want. Does it answer?

Comment: Yeah, I had been doing something similar to directly call Gmaps.loadMaps (i.e. as you say, not have window.onload = Gmaps.loadMaps()), but that seemed to still have an issue. So I looked at the internals of loadMaps and emulated what it does by calling window['load_' + key] (changed for my circumstances) directly (i.e. call the load function for the map). This got me farther along, but I'm getting a different undef issue. In the console though, I think I may have narrowed things down to being because I have no markers defined, but I don't want a marker defined on this map when first displayed.

Comment: Mmm, there was a bug in 1.1.3 when no markers were on the map. 1.1.4 corrects this issue

Comment: Ah, I'm running 1.1.2, I'll upgrade and see if that helps.

Comment: No change. I'll keep investigating.

Answer (score 1):

UPDATE: possibly only partly correct (i.e. I did have the problem that was outlined here, but calling Gmaps.loadMaps() still doesn't work).

2nd Update: I have had to alter the definition of the load_... to be on the Gmaps object and then alter Gmaps.loadMaps function accordingly. I've put in a pull request to the project at https://github.com/apneadiving/Google-Maps-for-Rails/pull/94.

---

The Gmaps.loadMaps() call wasn't the issue. So an alternative isn't necessary. The thing that was tripping me up is that in the partial enable_js was being called as false and the JavaScript that declares the new instance of the Gmaps4RailsGoogle and the function for loading it was not being called.

I have a custom version of the partial and in my case, even when enable_js (I interpret as "don't load javascript library files" for my app) is false, I still do the JavaScript that declares the new Gmaps4RailsGoogle instance and defines the load_... function.

That being said, the load_... function appears to be not working for me. It comes back with the following in my case:

TypeError: 'undefined' is not a function (evaluating 'window"load_" + key')

When I call the load_... function directly from the console (rather than the Gmaps.loadMaps call), I get a similar error:

```
"'undefined' is not a function (evaluating 'this.load_...()')"
```

Perhaps having to do with not having any markers declared? Any hints on that problem appreciated.

If I step through the steps in the load... function, the first bit that throws an error is .initialize(). Still investigating.

Comment: what is the content of your page (html and js) before and after the ajax call?

Comment: When I switch back to calling Gmaps.loadMaps() simply within a javascript_tag("Gmaps.loadMaps()") I get: TypeError: 'undefined' is not a function (evaluating 'window["load_" + key]()'). It looks like the load_... function, though defined in in the page before the Gmaps.loadMaps call, isn't being found. Perhaps I'm in the wrong scope?

Comment: I've put together the rendered html/js for the partial at https://gist.github.com/1218055. The meat of the relevant stuff starts at line 94.

Comment: By the way, I've confirmed that (at least with non-Ajax version) the maps work ok without having any markers. Thanks for fixing that in 1.1.4.

Comment: The info isn't in your gist, but I'm quite sure you haven't loaded the appropriate js files before your js code. Ideally, include these files manually in your html and tell the partial not to load them.

Comment: The following are coming up loaded in the head; http://maps.google.com/maps/api/js?sensor=false&amp;libraries=geometry,places, http://google-maps-utility-library-v3.googlecode.com/svn/tags/infobox/1.1.5/src/infobox.js, http://google-maps-utility-library-v3.googlecode.com/svn/tags/markerclusterer/1.0/src/markerclusterer_compiled.js, /javascripts/gmaps4rails/gmaps4rails.base.js, and /javascripts/gmaps4rails/gmaps4rails.googlemaps.js. Am I missing any?

Comment: That's fine. Do they appear before your scripts?

Comment: Yes, the js libs are loaded in the head and the scripts are included in the body of partial that is loaded via Ajax.